# Can you use Android's step detector/counter below KitKat 4.4?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-sensors

Can you use the "new" step [detector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-stepdetector)/counter sensors implemented in Android KitKat 4.4 and above in older versions of Android? I'm especially interested in the detector.

I am asking this because I want to make my app downwards-compatible below 4.4 and ask myself if there is a simple way to get these values. As they are probably software-implemented (I guess!) they should also work in older versions if you could reach the source. But I could not find it [anywhere](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/hardware). Are they included in the *Android Support Repository*?

I don't want to implement it by myself if avoidable, because of performance reasons, (maybe?) redundant work and simplicity.

Comment: If I remember correctly those implementations are coming from the Playstore Services as provided by google, which is @ https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview . You'll need to read that to figure out how it links up with your question. Also the ASR and Google Play Services are not synonymous.

Comment: Okay so I do find a step cadency sensor in the [overview](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#data_types_for_instantaneous_readings) and [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE). 

I will look at how to implement it soon and post results here/answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: The [Senor API doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#STRING_TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) states that the `TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR` is added in API level 20, it is only available after KitKat 4.4.

Comment: @ztan Yes, but all [android.hardware.Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html).STRING_TYPE_* were added at API level 20. But I am referring to the [com.google.android.gms.fitness.SensorsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SensorsApi) in the [Google Fit API](https://developers.google.com/fit/) and not the standard Android framework's sensors as suggested by _JoxTraex_.